# Writing to file in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash scripting, and I'm trying to output 2 columns of data. First column has `# vs # :` Second column has  correlation coefficient. I'm trying to output `1 vs 2 : 0.214213,` with the comma at the end to a file, but it outputs as `1 vs 2 : ,0.214213` with the comma in the middle. This is the line of bash commands that I'm using:

```
echo -e -n "$i vs $((i+1)) :\t" >> ./EEG_DATA/conc_corr_$conc.csv | corr ./EEG_DATA/ERP/ERP$conc/ERP$conc.$i.txt ./EEG_DATA/ERP/ERP$conc/ERP$conc.$((i+=1)).txt >> ./EEG_DATA/conc_corr_$conc.csv | echo -n ',' >>./EEG_DATA/conc_corr_$conc.csv
```

I'm not sure why the comma is being written in the middle when the command to `echo` the comma is at the end of the line. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since the length of your filenames makes it hard to understand what's happening, allow me to create a simplified version of your commands:

```
echo -e -n "$i vs $((i+1)) :\t" >> correlation.csv | 
corr conc.$i.txt conc.$((i+=1)).txt >> correlation.csv | 
echo -n ',' >>correlation.csv
```

You cannot write output to a file with `>>` and also pipe it into another command with `|` at the same time. If you want to write output to both the file and the pipe, you can use the `tee` command, but I am almost certain this is not your goal.

I believe you simply want to run the three commands, `echo`, `corr`, and another `echo`, one after the other, *without* connecting their output to the next command's input (which is the purpose of a pipe `|`).

My answer is similar to @cnd's, but I would replace **all** the `|` signs with semicolons, or simply write each command on its own line:

```
echo -e -n "$i vs $((i+1)) :\t" >> correlation.csv 
corr conc.$i.txt conc.$((i+=1)).txt >> correlation.csv
echo -n ',' >>correlation.csv
```

**Why your original approach doesn't work**: Commands that are piped together run in parallel. You can see that nicely with this test:

```
sleep 1234 | sleep 5678 | sleep 9012 &
ps -f
```

You will see all three `sleep`s sitting there and sleeping. In your case, the two `echo` commands and `corr` are launched in parallel as well, but the `echo`s produce their output faster than `corr`, which explains why the comma is written before the correlated value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mixing up your pipes and semicolons?
i.e. change that last | to ; to put the , at the end.

Comment: I tried it, and didn't work. Just tried executing them on separate lines instead of piping them.

Comment: if you execute the commands one after the other, without the pipe signs, the comma should appear at the end.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/478434)

Comment: This question says "Any help is greatly appreciated." - this is the answer that the poser needs because he has incorrectly assumed that writing out-of-order is a bash file problem, when the cause of his problem is a misunderstanding of pipe flow operations.

You need to stop trolling new users like me, and start reading and understanding the questions properly - if you do not know the answer, go away and do something else instead of dissuading us who know the answer to help these people. 
A bloodyminded literal answer to a question that's mistaken would be dumb.